# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedException since Angular 2 beta

Tags: angular, firebase

I updated Angular 2 to beta.0. and use the firebaseevent pipe from: https://github.com/sararob/angular2base

```
<tr *ngFor="#t of DBSERVER | firebaseevent:'child_added'">
    <td>{{t.Message}}</td>
    <td>{{t.Source}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now I get the error:

```
Error: Expression 'DBSERVER | firebaseevent:'child_added' in Log@21:10' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'. Current value: 'undefined'
    at ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedException.BaseException [as constructor]
```

It worked with alpha46. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, but this is the original repo FWIW: https://github.com/jeffbcross/pipeplay

Comment: See [#5918](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5918) and [#5950](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5950)

Comment: I am equally stuck with the same error messages, check https://github.com/meandemo/ng2-demo.git,  The master in on alpha.52 => OK, the beta branch in on beta.0 => lot of error: ... has changed after it was checked....

Comment: Switching back to prod mode corrects (hides) the problem:

      import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
      enableProdMode();
      bootstrap(MainCmp, [])

Comment: 'beta' branch of  github.com/meandemo/ng2-demo.git, has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right answer in comment :

> Switching back to prod mode corrects (hides) the problem: import
>   {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core'; enableProdMode();
>   bootstrap(MainCmp, []) – user3636086 4 hours ago
>
> 'beta' branch of github.com/meandemo/ng2-demo.git, has been updated.

Answer (score -2):

Please enable production mode
    enableProdMode();

Comment: That's not really a solution for the problem. This just hides it.

Comment: See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedException-class.html as @GünterZöchbauer says it's not a solution it just hides the problem.